# collection.find({}) doesnt work after many tries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building an api with express and mongoose and im using`db.collection(collection).find({})` expecting that i get all of my docs back (3 test docs in total) as seen from tutorials. It doesnt give me any errors when im executing a req from postman and that confuses me as im geting nothing, not even an empty object or array as a response. I have tried different examples, from different tutorials but nothing works. Is the syntax wrong?

```
import express from 'express'
import './connection.js'
const router = express.Router
const db = mongoose.connection;
const dtb = db.useDb('main').collection('products')

router.get('/true', async(req, res) => {
    try {
            const products = await dtb.find({})
            res.send(products).status(200)
        

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
})
```

Comment: where is connection? are you connected to mongo?

Comment: Yes I am it is just on another file that I didn’t link on the code I showed

Comment: Are you getting a response from the API in postman? If so, what status code? Or is it just hanging forever and not getting a response.

Comment: @Matt Yes i am getting a res of 200 but with no content. i checked and the docs are there so its not that there is no data to collect

Comment: To mark your question as solved, click the Checkmark button under the answer that solved it. 

Comment: @KevinB 2 days need to pass in order to mark my solution as the solution to my problem. For now, I wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after lookig again and again at my code I realized that the route `/true` was taken as a param by express as i have another route for `app.get('/:_id', getItem)`.
After changing the route to `/all/true` parsing the docs into an array and after some debugging, my getAll function looks like this and finally works :

```
export const getAll = app.get('/all/true', async(req, res) => {

    const products = await dtb.find({}).toArray().catch(console.error())

    res.send(products)


})
```

Comment: alternatively, if you moved this route to *before* the one with the param, it would have been handled by this route rather than the param'd route, while still letting other requests reach the param'd route. (however, making routes not cross is probably better anyway)